# Unable to use material UI icons .says module not found

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, icons

It is a simple program . i am trying to use a material UI search icon . i have installed both material UI core and material UI icons . Im still unable to use them . can someone explain me why.

```
import React from 'react';
import "../style components/Header.css";
import SearchIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Search';

function Header() {
    return (
        <div className="Header">
            <div className="header_left">
                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/FaceB.png" alt="" />
                <SearchIcon/>
                <div className="header_input">                   
                    <input type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div className="header_middle"></div>
            <div className="header_right"></div>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Header;
```

"this is the error"
./src/components/Header.jsx
Module not found: Can't resolve '@mui/icons-material/Search' in 'C:\Users\noushd\Desktop\Clone\facebook-clone\src\components'

Comment: Is there a space in there `import "../style components/Header.css";`?

Comment: yeah it is just the folder name which holds the css file for my component and that is working fine

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to put an space in a folder name. It should not work!

Comment: yeah i have corrected it now .but that doesnt sort my problem here

Answer (score 0):

The Material UI Icons module is dependant on the Material UI Core to display the icons. So make sure you installed the core module.

> These components use the MUI SvgIcon component to render the SVG path for each icon, and so have a peer-dependency on @materialui/core.

- https://mui.com/components/icons/#svg-material-icons

And just to add onto what [Hamidreza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3212379/hamidreza) said, you can use spaces in filenames but it's frowned upon as they might be misinterpreted by software that poorly supports them.

Comment: i have installed both the depandancies "npm install @mui/material" and "npm install @mui/icons-material" . I also tried with the old version "npm i @material-ui/core" and "npm i @material-ui/icons" .. and yes i have removed the space in btw the folder name now .

Comment: Are you still having no luck? I threw together a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-icon-example-6fq6u) using both the mui modules and the material-ui module and they both work after importing the core and other dependencies. Without seeing your package.js and the error log I can't guide you. But check out the sandbox and see if it helps at all.

Comment: Hi adam i was able to solve it . I had to install @emotion/react and  @emotion/styled to get it working but it used to work without them before .

Answer (score 0):

I had to install @emotion/react and  @emotion/styled to get it working but it used to work without them before .

Answer (score 0):

Solution1:- look at the package.json file material UI version and use the respective material UI.

Solution2:- Install the latest version of Material UI